# Model validation: Retrieving all rules registered by Entity Framework 4.1

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1

I'm using a DB-first approach with EF4.1. When I call `GetValidationErrors()` on the DbContext, EF validates all the entities that have been attached to the context and that's fine so far.

**My question is** whether there is a possibility to retrieve all the registered validation rules of a given EF Model before conducting the validation itself? I'd like to process and expose them to my front-end client in a special manner.

EF takes those rules probably out of the CSDL metadata of a given entity. Does anyone have a hint how I can get access to those?

thx

Comment: Reflection? Reflector to the rescue...

Comment: I would like someone to answer this...ahem!!!

Comment: @Raj I found the answer or at least an acceptable solution. I'll try to post it in the coming days....quite busy currently

Comment: Okay, keep me posted Juri! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Reflection to iterate over the model properties and pick up the various Data Annotation attributes. You can check specifically for ValidationAttribute.

Not sure how useful that would be though, unless you explicitly want to check for specific attributes (ie. RangeAttribute and its specific properties like Maximum and Minimum). This wouldn't work with custom validator attributes though since you'd have no idea what to check for...